# Double asterisk (**) operator gives different results

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following code

```
from werkzeug.datastructures import ImmutableMultiDict
f = ImmutableMultiDict([('name', ''), ('desc', 'example'), ('species', '1747')])
def print_data(name, desc, species):
    print(desc)

print_data(**f)
```

On python 3.6.1 the result is

```
['example']
```

And on python 3.7.2 the result is

```
'example'
```

I couldn't find any information about this change. And is seems strange that it is the result of the python version (BUT everything else is the same (werkzeug v1.0.1))

Am I right and this is a python thing? Can anyone point me to the release notes (Yes, I searched and didn't find...)

Comment: See this bug report: https://github.com/pallets/werkzeug/issues/1379

Comment: Sounds like the difference is probably caused by a change in the behaviour of `ImmutableMultiDict`.

Comment: @deceze - This is the answer. I'll accept it if you make it an official one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, CPython has changed behaviour in 3.7.1. Paraphrasing [this bug report](https://github.com/pallets/werkzeug/issues/1379) on Werkzeug, which also contains the solution:

> [CPython [..] changed [..] the implementation of `**kwargs` to unpack using `data.items()` instead of `dict.items(data)`](https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/8624). `MultiDict.items()` always returned the first value, so CPython [was] previously [..] using `dict.items(data)` [..]
>
> ```
> m = MultiDict({"x": [1, 2]})
> m.items()
> [("x", 1)]
> dict.items(m)
> [("x", [1, 2])]
> ```
>
> There's not really anything Werkzeug can do about this, we're not going to change how `MultiDict.items()` works.
>
> I'm not even sure if `**MultiDict` was ever intended to work. Use `data.as_dict(flat=False)` to get a `dict` to unpack.
>
> ```
> m.as_dict(flat=False)
> {"x": [1, 2]}
> fn(**m.as_dict(flat=False))
> {"x": [1, 2]}
> ```